# How to calculate speed vertices for 3d sphere - explosion (particle system in)

Tags: vector, particle-system

I am making a 3d particle system and I wonder how to make an explosion. My function will specify the number of particles that will create explosion effect. It will look like a growing sphere. My question is: how to calculate velocity Vector3 for every particle?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to ensure that you don't have any clumping or biases, you're going to need to generate a [uniform spherical distribution](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematica/Uniform_Spherical_Distribution) of points (which, as the link shows, is intuitive but somewhat non-trivial).

To create the animation in question, imagine a sphere of `radius = 1` centered at the origin.  If you then select a uniform spherical distribution of points, you can set your `vector = point - origin`.  If you then translate that vector to originate at your point of explosion, you have a uniform distribution of vectors pointing out from the detonation.

Now, multiply those vectors by `time * explosion speed` and you have most of your animation.  Keep in mind, a video game is going to call for a slower speed than real life. Watch some Mybusters videos for examples of supersonic shockwaves - neat on television but not as fun in a fame.

Comment: @BrianVandenberg - you can have the next one.  Uniform distribution type questions seem to come up a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The direction should be completely random, while the speed will have to be tuned by hand. Just keep adjusting it until you get a result that looks good, there is no correct answer.